# Lifetime bound of the form T: 'a

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am trying to understand what `T: 'a` means, where, I guess, `T` is a type and `'a` is a lifetime.

I understand what `'a: 'b` means: `x`(`'a`) outlives `y`(`'b`) and so we cannot assign `y` to `x` in the following code

```
fn foo<'a, 'b, T>(mut x: &'a T, mut y: &'b T) 
   where 'a: 'b {
  x = y; //compile time error
}
```

[This reference book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html) writes

> `T: 'a` means that all lifetime parameters of `T` outlive `'a`.

But I am confused by the "*all lifetime parameters of `T`*". What is a "*lifetime parameter of (type?) T*" ? I know that `'a` is a lifetime of `x` in this signature `fn foo<'a, T>(x: &'a T)`. Does it mean the same thing?

Could someone explain what `T:'a` means by giving an example? I can't even imagine where we could use it and why.

Comment: Imagine a type `struct Foo<'b, 'c> {bar: &'b str, boo: &'c [u8] }`. T:'a would mean that than calling foo::<Foo>() would guarantee that 'b and 'c are at least 'a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While references can have lifetimes, types can have lifetimes too. The simplest example would probably be:

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    x: &'a i32
}
```

If you construct a struct of type `Foo` (let's call this instance `foo`) with a reference to an `i32` (let's call this `num`) on the local stack, then `foo` cannot live longer than the scope of `num`, regardless of the scope of `foo` itself. It's a lifetime without a reference (to the type, at least).

Let's take a look at a real world example of this: [`Box::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak):

```rust
pub fn leak<'a>(b: Box<T>) -> &'a mut T
where
    T: 'a,
```

The type signature basically says that, given a box, you can create a reference to its value for any lifetime **as long as the value itself is capable of lasting for that lifetime**. So, we could create a `&'static i32` with `Box::leak`, since `i32` has nothing restricting its lifetime, but we can't create a `&'static Foo` that references a stack integer, as it has a reference restricting its lifetime.

Note that if you're testing this locally, things like `&5` will actually create a `&'static i32` due to [rvalue static promotion](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1414-rvalue_static_promotion.html), so you might want to change the `i32` to an unpromotable type like `String`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I don't understand how a Type can "live". I understand that a variable can live (on a stack or heap), reference can live (ref is simply a pointer, 4 byte value), instance of a struct can live... but type (u32, Foo, str...) are not something that live, they are used to declare a var (kinda inform compiler that a variable will be of some size). Am I wrong?

Comment: @HardFork What if your struct contains a reference though?

Comment: Right. Then it must have a lifetime somehow related to that ref.

Comment: @Applet123, one more thing. We have `&'a mut T` and `where T: 'a`. Do `&'a mut T` say "the REF to the var has lifetime 'a" and `T: 'a`  say "type T outlives 'a"? I mean `&'a mut T` is not enough, right?

Comment: `&'a mut T` means that the reference has lifetime `'a`, and the `T: 'a` is implied (but means that `T` should be able to outlive or match `'a`).

Comment: If `T: 'a` is implied by `&'a mut T` then why do we need to write  `where T: 'a`? That's what really confused me.

Comment: From the comment next to the function declaration: "Technically not needed, but kept to be explicit."