# life time of a trait object reference

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

With `FooClass` that implements `FooTrait`, and `Bar` that takes the reference of a `FooTrait` object, the code is working:

```
trait FooTrait {
    fn print(self);
}

struct FooClass {}

impl FooTrait for FooClass {
    fn print(self) {
        println!("It's a Foo");
    }
}

struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: &'a (dyn FooTrait),
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    fn new(_foo: &'a (dyn FooTrait)) -> Bar<'a> {
        Bar { foo: _foo }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = FooClass {};
    let bar = Bar::new(&foo);
    println!("hello world");
}
```

But for

```
struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: &'a (dyn FooTrait),
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    fn new(_foo: &'a (dyn FooTrait)) -> Bar<'a> {
        Bar { foo: _foo }
    }
}
```

I have also seen they are written as

```
struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: &'a (dyn FooTrait + 'a),
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    fn new(_foo: &'a (dyn FooTrait + 'a)) -> Bar<'a> {
        Bar { foo: _foo }
    }
}
```

I think I understand that `struct Bar<'a> { foo: &'a (dyn FooTrait + 'a), }` says, `foo` should live at least as long as `Bar` so that reference stay valid. But this explains only `Bar<'a>` and `foo: &'a`, that I don't see what does `+ 'a` do after `dyn FooTrait` in the parentheses. Also, removing `+'a` doesn't seems to break the program. Can someone explain to me the purpose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lifetime bound of the form T: 'a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65520042/lifetime-bound-of-the-form-t-a)

Answer (score 2):

The `+ 'a` says that not only does the concrete type need to implement `FooTrait`, but it also may not itself contain references that live shorter than `'a`.

Consider:

```
struct FooWithRefs<'b> { reff: &'b i32, }
impl <'b> FooTrait for FooWithRefs<'b> { ... }

fn main() {
    let i = 100;
    let foo = FooWithRefs { reff: &i };
    let bar = Bar::new(&foo);
    println!("hello world");
}
```

The compiler needs to know that not only does `foo` not disappear during the lifetime of `bar`, but also that nothing `foo` itself references goes out of scope. The `+ 'a` condition ensures this.

(I can't think of a way to write an example that violates this condition that won't also violate the mere creation of the `FooWithRefs` though.)

I don't know the exact semantics of omitting the lifetime bound, though. Trying it out suggests that it implicitly uses the same bound.

[See it on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f06a7452010d77c32b34c302cc668877)

Comment: Default rules for trait bounds (with examples):
https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes

Comment: quote: "I can't think of a way to write an example that violates this condition that won't also violate the mere creation of the `FooWithRefs` though." If such condition doesn't exist, then such feature is redundant, right?